# Método de ordenação Bubblesort com alocação dinâmica + ponteiro

Tags: c

Olá, pessoal. Estou tentando resolver um exercício, por método de ordenação bubblesorte e alocação dinâmica (Sem ponteiros e sem alocação dinâmica o exercício fica mais fácil, entretanto, o professor pediu para fazer com AD). O exercício é simples, é dizer quantas vezes o problema vai rodar, passar a quantidade de números a serem reordenados e, jogar na tela. Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main(){
    int qt,n,i,j,aux;
    int *p;
    scanf("%d",&qt);

    while(qt!=0){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        p = (int *) calloc(n, sizeof(int));

          for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                scanf("%d",(p+i));

          }

         /* for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                printf("%d\n",*p); /* Neste for, estou testando se o ponteiro está pegando os números, e está */
                ++p;
          } */

          for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
            for(j=n-1; j>i; j--){
                if(*p < *(p-1)){
                    aux = *p;
                    *p = *(p-1);
                    *(p-1) = aux;

                }
            }
          }
          for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("%d ",*p);
            ++p;
          }
          printf("\n");

          free(p);




        qt--;
    }
```

}

Enfim, o erro acontece no método de ordenação, quando no final, eu printo os valores reordenados, aparecem apenas lixos. Eu sei que estou errando no método de ordenação, já tentei colocar um ++p ou --p, mas de nada adiantou. Creio que aquele *(p-1) esteja errado. Alguém poderia me dizer o erro? Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei mais fácil refazer o programa do que explicar os erros individualmente...

Pontos a observar:

1) Se você tem  `int* p` então `*(p + i)` é a mesma coisa que `p[i]`.

2) Comentários /* */ não aninham, isto é, `/* ..... */ ... */` em geral vai 
   dar erro na compilação (se você tiver sorte)

3) cuidado ao digitar, não troque i, 1, l (e outros casos parecidos)

4) use mais espaços, fica mais fácil visualizar o código...por exemplo, isto aqui é ruim: `while(qt!=0)`, use `while (qt != 0)`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int *p;
   int qt, n, i, j, aux;

   printf("\nQuantas rodadas ? ");
   scanf("%d",&qt);

   while (qt != 0)
   {
      printf("\nQuantos numeros ? ");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      p = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));

      // printf("Digites %d numeros e tecle ENTER: ", n);
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
         printf("%d/%d: ", i+1, n);
         scanf("%d", (p+i));
      }

      for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
      {
         for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
         {
            if (p[i] > p[j])
            {
               aux = p[i];
               p[i] = p[j];
               p[j] = aux;
             } // if
         } // for j
       } // for i

       for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
          printf("%d ", p[i]);
       }

       printf("\n");

       free(p);

       qt--;

   } // while

}
```

That's all for now folks :)

Comment: Obrigado, José X. Seguirei suas dicas. Uma pergunta, que método é esse que você usou para ordenar?

Comment: @Fiodor é o próprio bubble sort, só que fazendo as comparações a partir do início e não do final, acho que é mais natural